# Django Login Form / Invalid User

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django and started building a simple login form. My view is working(redirecting to '/person/) when providing authenticated Username/Password. But it's throwing an ERROR ''AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'" when providing invalid credentials. Below is my view.

```
#views.py
def userlogin(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    auth_login(request, user)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            print("User is valid, active and authenticated")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/person')
        else:
            print("The password is valid, but the account has been disabled!")
            # return HttpResponseRedirect('/person/login')
            return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        print("The username and password were incorrect.")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/person/login')

    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to login a user (`'AnonymousUser'`) whose credentials are invalid.

Move the `auth_login` logic into the block for authenticated users:

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
         auth_login(request, user)
```